# A lot of arp requests from a single system

Tags: networking, wireshark

My network uses static IP addresses and has a router. I used wireshark to detect a lot of arp requests from a single system, which seems to be running abnormally to me.

As I'm new to wireshark I don't know how to solve this problem. Please Help.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: alot of arp requests]

Is this behavior normal?

Its ip address is 10.0.0.6 and routers ip is 10.0.0.1

P.S. earlier rsyslog was configured on the system which sent logs to the system at the ip address 10.0.0.5

Comment: Is the computer at 10.0.0.6 running Ubuntu? If so, what services is it running?

Comment: Yes it is. Its ip address is 10.0.0.6 and the router's ip address is 10.0.0.1

Comment: Again, what's it running in the way of applications and services?

Comment: It's just a normal system with Ubuntu 12.04 and configured with LAMP. It's used for development.

Comment: The only thing I see is that your ARP cache seems not to be working, or its expires way too quickly. Normally, your systems asks once for the ARP then caches it, so it doesn't have to ask for it again (speeding up next connections).

Comment: Is there a way to check my arp cache memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Oli said depends on the services you have on your system that has ip 10.0.0.6.

ARP traffic is quite normal, in your screenshot I can see only you system trying to contact 3 IP address (10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.12 and 10.0.0.11) in a perfect and the correct way (also repetitions are normal).
Here some slides on ARP proto: http://netgroup.polito.it/teaching/cn/arp_E_A_3x.pdf

Probably on your system there is a service that "scans" the network.
The problem is that you cannot use WireShark to find witch is the service that produce this probes as WS works at network layer.
I suggest the use of "netstat -an" on the 10.0.0.6 system to detect all the services running on it.

Comment: @Tarun : The ARP cache can be listed issuing an "`arp -an`" command (use "`arp --help`" for other options).  

@Braiam : The ARP cache is filled only if there is a answer by the queried, but if the 10.0.0.6 system is not receiving an answer than it can retry at libitum.